# Phpunit starts all the tests or not starts all the tests, ignoring the config

Tags: phpunit, symfony-3.3

My project contains 2 packages, and I want to run tests in only one of them. Used **symfony 3.3** and **phpunit 6.3.0**

phpunit.xml.dist

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/6.3/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="./src/CoreBundle/Tests/autoloadWithIsolatedDatabase.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="App">
            <directory>src/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

And structure of the project

[image: structure]

This configuration will run all the tests from AppBundle and CoreBundle (in the second there are no tests), and if you change

```
<directory>src/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
```

to

```
<directory>src/CoreBundle/Tests</directory>
```

then there will be no tests at all. I can not understand what's wrong

Comment: If I write the tests in different folders in the tests folder - the settings work (`<directory>tests/AppBundle</directory>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start of by how your phpunit.xml.dist is configured. You have one test suite defined:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="App">
        <directory>src/AppBundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This is the place phpunit will look into for tests. They have to conform to the usual conventions like having a file name ending in `Test` and each test method must be prefixed with a `test`.

Also from your screenshot I can gather that you have a top level tests/ folder (right next to app/, src/, etc.). This is probably where your other tests are placed in.

The second folder is where you should also place your tests from the AppBundle if you follow the best practices: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html

I think this was established sometime during the 3.x release cycle.

In theory you should be able to copy src/AppBundle/Tests to tests/AppBundle and hopefully everything still works. Now you can update your test suite configuration to:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="App">
        <directory>tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Your filter can stay in place as src/CoreBundle/Tests does not actually contain test-classes, only helpers used for tests.

Now that you have all tests in one big tests folder separated by bundle you might want to do a search on this folder for classes extending `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. Since PHPUnit 6.0 introduced namespaces those need to be updated with `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` otherwise PHPUnit will ignore those tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did this in principle, all tests were moved to the tests folder, because There configs work.